# Windows Phone 8 app navigation issue

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have started developing a Windows Phone app from an existing cordova installation (platforms:android, ios). It works well in both of these, but I'm having issues on wp8 platform.
We initially had an issue desribed here: [PhoneGap app crashes on WP8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819485/phonegap-app-crashes-on-wp8-1) , and proposed solution worked well in this case too.
But - our app has a login screen, where after successful login in we are getting to the main screen. Main screen contains 6 navigation items. Clicking on them suppose to direct to another page/view (we are using angular). Instead we are presented with following message:

[image]

I haven't found much on web, except perhaps this: ["You need to install an app for this task" error with Windows Phone 8 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539583/you-need-to-install-an-app-for-this-task-error-with-windows-phone-8-app). This doesn't work in our scenario. Also you can notice that nav items icons are not being loaded too, perhaps this might be related to the first issue.

Has anyone any advice on that?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line of code into your angular config
 $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):/);

Solution found on http://www.stephenpauladams.com/articles/angularjs-cordova-windows-phone-quirk/

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here... I found out it happens only with hyperlinks with a querystring. Hyperlinks without querystring data will load without any problem, but if you have a link with querystring data, it gives you the error... strange problem...